# Can't do anything with external hard drive, “.Trashes” is probably the boogyman

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, permission, trash, disk-format

I bought an external Samsung hard drive today. But I'm not able to do anything with it. Here are the problems I'm having:

- I can't put anything on the hard drive. Finder gets stuck at 'preparing copying files'
- I can delete anything on the hard drive *system files*, except the
  folder ".Trashes". It gives error 'Unexpected error: -50'
- I tried to empty the trash can, but nothing changes.
- I set the file permission on the .Trashes to read/write everyone,
  doesn't change a thing
- Trying to format the whole drive with Disk Utility, but quits at
  start, because the drive cannot be deactivated.

I've tried a few terminal commands

```
sudo -s -r rf /Volumes/Untitled\ 1/.Trashes` //Directory not empty  
-r rf /Volumes/Untitled\ 1/.Trashes` //No permissions
```

Also

```
cd /Volumes ls -al cd name_of_partition ls -al
rm -rf .Trashes
```

Again: Permission error.

Also:

- I can't change drive permissions via Disk Utility, via the button 'recover drive permissions', because it is 'blank'

One thing that really bothers me: I really want to format the partition, but every time it says 'Disk cannot be deactivated', when trying to recover, wipe or format.

I really can't figure out how to delete .Trashes, format the drive or get the damn thing working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the exact steps, but maybe you do or someone else does. If you use a bootable OS X installer, there is a menu option to open Disk Utility. At that point, the drive should be fully configurable. When you write "deactivated", I assume you mean unmounted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. After trying everything sudo I could do under the sun, manually trying to remove the .Trashes file through finder, etc I wound up just reformatting the drive.

The reformat took significantly less time than me trying to figure out how to get the drive empty. Probably better for the drive, anyway.